# Where does Visual Studio 2003 store connections created using server explorer

Tags: visual-studio, server-explorer

I am creating a connection to an SAP system and want to manually modify the connectionString. Is it possible to do this?

Where does Visual Studio 2003 store connections created using server explorer

Comment: Do you mean modify the connection a new app is using, after you've created it with Server Explorer and used it in the app?
Or just edit the connection recorded in Server Explorer, which won't affect anything other than future connections?

Answer (score 3):

i have vs 2008, so this might be different - but maybe it still helps:

- the connection string is in `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\ServerExplorer\DefaultView.SEView` (for vs 2003, this would probably be `...\7.1\...`. to find the value of `%APPDATA%`, do `echo %APPDATA%` in a `cmd` shell)
- however, it is a `EncryptedConnectionString`, something like `<EncryptedConnectionString id="ref-18">01000000D08C9DDF0115D1118C7A00C04FC297EB0100000...</EncryptedConnectionString>` - so you cannot edit it manually.